# How to pass a dictionary in argparse and then use it in a class method in python

Tags: python, dictionary, argparse

I am having trouble passing a dictionary in the argparse in python. I have tried many solutions including the json.loads but nothing is working. After passing the dictionary in argparse I want to use it as a parameter in a class method. 
It has become a nightmare of mine now.

Thank you in advance!!

Comment: Where is the code for your current attempt? What didn't work with using `json`?

Comment: We can't help without seeing what you tried and how it went wrong.

Comment: Where is the dictionary and your code? considering passing the name of a file via argparse and load the dict into your code using `json`.

Comment: Keep your parser simple, and do any 'dictionary' decoding after parsing.  Also look at `sys.argv[1:]`, the list of strings that the parser sees.  Beware that the shell might mangle your input if not adequately quoted.